# Require a particular party signature in a corda transaction

Tags: kotlin, corda

I have a particular Node/Party (say bank) on the network that has to be signer of some type of transaction how do I reflect that ?
(For instance partyA wants to create a account and I need the bank to validate that every time)

For now I'm trying to find a way to do it in the contract

```
private fun verifyCreate(tx: LedgerTransaction) = requireThat {
      "There should be an actual output to the creation" using (tx.outputsOfType<StockAccountState>().size == 1)

      val outStockAccountState =tx.outRefsOfType<StockAccountState>().single();
       "There should be No inputs when creating an account" using (tx.inputs.isEmpty())
       val neededParty = Party(???) // How do I get either the certificate or the name and publickey ?? 
        val expectedSigners = listOf(outStockAccountState.state.data.custodian, neededParty)

}
```

Basically I need to create the Bank party to check against the actual signers but I don't know how to.

Maybe there is another way to do it but I don't know which

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your `StockAccountState` has a field called `val bank :Party`, so your contract verifies that the signers consist of `outStockAccountState.bank`.